# Selenium: How to click on the install plugins button?

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x

I use Selenium to launch Firefox browser with a given URL of my choice. Some websites ask the permission of the user to click on a button that appears on the top of the website's page to  install some plugins in order to view the content (load it) correctly. 

How could I click automatically on that button ?

Comment: Do you know which plugins would be missing beforehand?

Comment: @alecxe No, I do not know. Will this have an impact over the code itself ?

Comment: Is hiding the message an option or you need to actually install the plugins?

Comment: @alecxe I do not want to hide that message optionally, I want to install those plugins instead automatically. I need this for a security test.

Comment: @alecxe I spied even lot of of your answers with which you helped others: so I know your answers are better than the best courses/tutorials :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is not generated by javascript, it is the browser itself. So, the only way you can control it is via predefined capabilities, or custom profile:

- set [`plugins.hide_infobar_for_missing_plugin`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Plugins.hide_infobar_for_missing_plugin) setting which would not let the popup to appear

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
  profile.set_preference('plugins.hide_infobar_for_missing_plugin', True)

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
  ```
- set [`plugin.default_plugin_disabled`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries#Plugin.) to `False` (not tested)

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
  profile.set_preference('plugin.default_plugin_disabled', False)

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
  ```

Also see:

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/731979

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is not a JS alert. I accept your answer without being able to test it right now because according to all your generous past help, I  can only trust the information you give either to me or to others. All my respect for You, Alexander.

Comment: @Begueradj it might not work since I haven't personally tested it. In case it doesn't work, I have some other ideas - let me know if it helped or not. Thank you!

Comment: Do not worry, dear Alexander, I could deal with any eventual errors to be raised but now I have full time to deal with my troubles unlike in the last months. I am sure you gave me the right hint at least, so everything will be simpler to deal later since I have time now. Thank You .

Answer (score 0):

If they are javascript alert boxes, you can use `switch_to_alert`:

```
alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
```

If they are not part of the web page, you will need to use a tool such as AutoIt to interact with them.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However I can not test it for the moment. I will test it when I am on my other laptop and see if it works. I just wonder if we really can treat it as an alert and not as a button or somethong else.

Comment: And no, they are not JS alert boxes.